# Append HTML table data to emptry dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am unsure how to add the column data to the empty dataframe.
Here is my code.

```py
!pip install bs4 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks?utm_medium=Exinfluencer&utm_source=Exinfluencer&utm_content=000026UJ&utm_term=10006555&utm_id=NA-SkillsNetwork-Channel-SkillsNetworkCoursesIBMDeveloperSkillsNetworkPY0221ENSkillsNetwork23455645-2021-01-01'

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.content 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup= BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Market Cap (US$ Billion)"])

import pandas as pd

for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[3].find_all('tr'):

    col = row.find_all('td')
```

When I use this code

```py
data.head(5)
```

I retrieve an empty Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This was a lot of digging and troubleshooting... but I keep forgetting that its always the case with webscraping.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks?utm_medium=Exinfluencer&utm_source=Exinfluencer&utm_content=000026UJ&utm_term=10006555&utm_id=NA-SkillsNetwork-Channel-SkillsNetworkCoursesIBMDeveloperSkillsNetworkPY0221ENSkillsNetwork23455645-2021-01-01'

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

data = {
    'Name': [],
    'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': []
}

x = soup.find_all('tbody')[3].find_all('tr')
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    data['Name'].append(str(x[i].find_all('td')[1].find_all('a')[1]).split('>')[1][:-3])
    data['Market Cap (US$ Billion)'].append(str(x[i].find_all('td')[2])[4:-6])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
```